# Creating a transition plot with three columns

Tags: r, plot

I have data consisting of multiple classes (in this example three classes) of test subjects but the classes vary based on three time points: genotype, early phenotype and late phenotype stages.

Here is the sample data:

```
genotype<-cbind(c(rep("A",100),rep("B",100),rep("C",100)))
early_phenotype<-cbind(c(rep("A",75),rep("B",75),rep("C",75),rep("A",75)))
late_phenotype<-cbind(c(rep("A",50),rep("B",100),rep("C",100),rep("A",50)))
df<-cbind(genotype,early_phenotype,late_phenotype)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df)<-c("genotype","early_phenotype","late_phenotype")
```

I would like to produce what is commonly referred a "transition plot". The closest I have gotten is this:

```
library(Gmisc)
transitionPlot(table(df[,1:2]), txt_start_clr = "black", txt_end_clr = "black", fill_start_box = "white", fill_end_box = "white")
```

... which producing this plot:
[image]

But I am trying to achieve two things that this plot does not have:

1. I want more than two columns, in this example three columns: genotype, early phenotype, and late phenotype. In this example, it would look like this (I achieved this in Photoshop, not in R)
   [image]
2. Instead of single arrows with different weights that connects two boxes, I would much rather have multiple arrows with jitter / transparency where each arrow would represent an individual observation, and would appear something like this:
   [image]

Any suggestions?

P.S. I don't really care about the curved edges of the boxes, or the fancy shadows.

Comment: More than 2 columns is possible using the [Gmisc::Transition-class](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Gmisc/vignettes/Transition-class.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. I want more than two columns, in this example three columns
> 2. Instead of single arrows with different weights that connects two
>      boxes, I would much rather have multiple arrows

Maybe try something using `igraph`:

```
m <- sapply(1:3, function(x) paste0(df[, x], x))
el <- rbind(m[, 1:2], m[, 2:3])
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_edgelist(el)
coords <- layout.norm(t(sapply(strsplit(V(g)$name, ""), function(x) as.numeric(c(-match(x[1], LETTERS), x[2])))))
plot(g, layout=coords[, 2:1])
```

[image]

Comment: looks promising, never heard of `igraph` before. Is there a way to change the spindle-shaped arrows to be less overwhelming? The real data has 1000+ observations so I'd rather employ alpha / transparency (I added sample picture in my above post)

Comment: Have a look at `?igraph.plotting` - you can for instance add `edge.arrow.size=0.5` to decrease the arrow size. It seems as if an `edge.color` with alpha (e.g. "#99999966`) does not work.

Comment: I see, without alpha though it would look like a solid spindle